# How to send verification code and retrieve it in android

Tags: android, web-services, web, gmail-api, email-verification

I am developing an application using web services(Volly). I just want to create

> Forget password module

I am taking email from user. I just want to send verification code to that particular email address so that user can put that code and rest his/her password.

Answer (score 0):

The reason people are down voting your post is because Stack Overflow isn't meant to be used as a place were people just write code for you. You can easily look this up. If you have a specific question, you can ask it here.